# URL Routing Path issue in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have really weird problem with url routing. I defined 3 routes for menu bar like that

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Article", "Article/{id}/{title}", "~/article.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Contact", "Contact", "~/contact.aspx");            
routes.MapPageRoute("Category","Category/{id}/{name}","~/category.aspx");
```

when i click to contact i get `www.website.com/Contact` and then i click to an article i get `www.website.com/Article/id/title` and all links are working.

However when i click an article firstly and then click contact, i have `www.website.com/Article/id/title/contact`, or `www.website/category/id/name/contact`

This problem only occurs when clicking from parameter routes to nonparameter routes. I will be glad if u give any idea. Thank you.

Comment: You've shown us the routing, but not how you're creating the routes in your markup.

Comment: here my route creating 

 `<a href='<%# GetRouteUrl("Article", new { id = Eval("ArticleID") ,title=Eval("ArticleTitle") })%>'>`

and my nonparameter link in menubar is 

`<a href="Contact">Contact</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contact link isn't application root relative. You need to make it application root relative. The easiest way in Web Forms is to switch to use a control instead of plain anchor tags.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Contact" Text="Contact" />
```

Otherwise, when you try to navigate to Contact without making it application root relative, it assumes that Contact is one below the level of the last segment in the current URL (because URL's used to be tied to directories rather than semantic routes, ex: in `www.website.com/Article/id/title` it thinks title is the directory).

Note, you could also do some inline C# in a plain anchor tag similar to the way you did `GetRouteUrl`, but I can't remember off the top of my head the correct function call to use.`ResolveUrl` or `ResolveClientUrl` or something like that.